# Load nextLevel with a button click

Tags: unity, scenemanager

Can anyone help me someone with this code?

I'd like to go to the next level by clicking a button: example my level name is L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7 and when I finish level L1, I want to go to level L2 with the click of a button, and from L5 go to L6 like this.

```
public class GameLevels : MonoBehaviour {

 public Button Play;
 private int idLevel;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () 
 {
     idLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("idLevel");
     Play.interactable = false;
 }
 public void SelectLevel(int i){
     idLevel = i;
     PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("idLevel", idLevel);
     Play.interactable = true;
 }

 public void LoadLevel(string Levels)
 {
     SceneManager.LoadScene (Levels);
 }
 public void Replay()
 {
     SceneManager.LoadScene ("L" + idLevel.ToString ());
 }
 public void loadNextLevel() 
 {

 }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: What is it you are looking for? How to get the button input?

Comment: Problem is i dont know how to input the next level code for example if i finish level 1 "L1" with press button to go in level 2 "L2" and if i finish level 2 "L2" with press again that button to go level 3 "L3".

Comment: Don't you have the "idLevel"? Why something like `SceneManager.LoadScene ("L" + (idLevel + 1).ToString ());`does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the Replay button and it works (As we don't have the full code, I'm not sure if it works but I'm assuming it does):

```
public void Replay()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene ("L" + idLevel.ToString ());
}
```

Then it stands to reason that the following should be the next level's code:

```
public void loadNextLevel() 
{
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("idLevel", idLevel+1);
SceneManager.LoadScene ("L" + (idLevel+1).ToString ());
}
```

Since idLevel is declared as an int, you can just add 1 and then turn it into a string.

You can also do this (when you load the next level, idLevel will be reset if I'm not mistaken, so it should be safe to do it this way too):

```
public void loadNextLevel() 
{
idLevel++;
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("idLevel", idLevel);
SceneManager.LoadScene ("L" + idLevel.ToString ());
}
```

P.S. You shouldn't have to turn it into a string because when you add an int to a string, it will also act as a string. Just make sure you do the math before the string addition, so don't forget to use the parentheses where we do `(idLevel+1)`. So, `SceneManager.LoadScene ("L" + (idLevel+1));` should also work.

Comment: Hello this don`t work because is load L2 but if i finish L2 don`t load L3 but back me again in L2 and same load L2,L2,L2.

Comment: Did you remember to set the PlayerPrefs variable you're taking this value from? I will make necessary edits in the last part (in a minute), use that code instead.

Comment: Thank you so much sir i solved the problem public void loadNextLevel() 
{
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("idLevel", idLevel+1);
SceneManager.LoadScene ("L" + (idLevel+1).ToString ());
} thi code is correct code :D

Comment: i created the main menu screen and game play in same scene. if player lost  in game over page it ll show a button replay. if i hit replay the game wants to start directly. it don't want to show main menu screen again. how can i do that?

Comment: @ManojBalajiM You could just make a global variable, `public static bool levelRestart = false;` then set that to true when the player pushes the replay button. Then check whether the level is a restart or not in the menu's `Start()` function and close the menu if it is then set the variable to false after that. Remember that to access a global variable, you need to specify the script's name and then access it, i.e. `GlobalVars.levelRestart` and do keep in mind globals are somewhat volatile, since they can be accessed from anywhere. Though you should really ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

try the simple code. it ll solve your problem

//to reload the Level

```
public void Replay(){
    Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);
}
```

//To load next level

```
public void NxtLevel(){
    Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel + 1);
}
```

this ll load the level by using level id. Located in build settings -> Scenes in build.

Answer (score -3):

Its may look like this :

```
 public class GameLevels : MonoBehaviour {

 public Button Play;
 private int idLevel;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () 
 {
     idLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("idLevel");
     Play.interactable = false;
 }
 public void SelectLevel(int i){
     idLevel = i;
     PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("idLevel", idLevel);
     Play.interactable = true;
 }

 public void LoadLevel(string Levels)
 {
     SceneManager.LoadScene (Levels);
 }
 public void Replay()
 {
     SceneManager.LoadScene ("L" + idLevel.ToString ());
 }
 public void loadNextLevel() 
 {
  int idLevelSecond = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("idLevel");
  string thelevelnumber = idLevelSecond.ToString();
  string leveltoload = "L" + thelevelnumber;
  Debug.Log(leveltoload);
  SceneManager.LoadScene(leveltoload);
 }
}
```

**UNTESTED !**  if the code did not work, tell me.

Comment: Isn't it going to load the same level as before?

Comment: i don't know how to increase value in player perfs , editing to add comment so he would add it to himself , wait

Comment: okay edited . ..

Comment: I am not the OP, I am not going to try, I downvoted because I did not find any explanation in the answer, just some unindented code.

Comment: he asked " i don't know how to do it in code " , not " what should i do to load next level "

Comment: let me edit to show he asked that

Comment: now look at the edit

Comment: 1- Code without explanation has absolutly 0 interest, even if it is what OP asked. 2- Your answer is bad in several ways. 3- You should learn to accept critism without acting like a 5 years old child.

Comment: Please don't use your answer as a medium to reply to comments.

Comment: It`s load same level again.